# SQL Query - pulling a query with a null value

Tags: mysql, sql, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm currently using an API through Azure to connect to my app. I'm running a query which populates the list view for the user's medications. The user has the choice whether to add a diagnosis along with their medication, or not. If the user adds a medication and diagnosis, the query is successful and will populate the database and list view. But if the user does not add a diagnosis, the database is updated successfully and the `userdiagnosis` field is blank, but it will not show up on the list view on the app.

Is there any way to allow a null value to run in the query and still pull the data successfully?

This is my current query:

```
var api = {
// an example of executing a SQL statement directly
get: (request, response, next) => {
    var query = {
        sql: 'SELECT  dbo.usermedication.id, \
        dbo.medicine.id AS medicationid,  \
        dbo.medicine.medname, \
        dbo.usermedication.isactive, \
        dbo.usermedication.reminder, \
        dbo.usermedication.communityfeedback, \
        dbo.usermedication.frequency, \
        dbo.usermedication.directions, \
        dbo.medicine.dosage, \
        dbo.usermedication.datetimetotake,  \
        dbo.userdiagnosis.id as "userdiagnosisid", \
        dbo.diagnosis.id AS diagnosisid, \
        dbo.diagnosis.diagnosistext \
        FROM dbo.usermedication 
        INNER JOIN dbo.medicine ON dbo.usermedication.medicationid = dbo.medicine.id  
        INNER JOIN dbo.userdiagnosis ON dbo.usermedication.userdiagnosisid = dbo.userdiagnosis.id  
        INNER JOIN dbo.diagnosis ON dbo.userdiagnosis.diagnosisid = dbo.diagnosis.id 
        WHERE dbo.usermedication.userid = @userid AND dbo.usermedication.isactive = 1',
        parameters: [
            { name: 'userid', value: request.query.userid }
        ]
    };

    request.azureMobile.data.execute(query)
        .then(function (results) {
            response.json(results);
        });
}
```

};

```
module.exports = api;
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand from your given problem statement, if user does not add diagnosis, then the dbo.diagnosis table will not have an entry but dbo.usermedication will get updated successfully.
Since you have used INNER JOIN on these tables, obviously the list will not have since there is no matching record in dbo.diagnosis table.

If you consider LEFT JOIN on dbo.diagnosis then you will be able to fetch the record from userMedication table even if the value is null in diagnosis table.

Give it a try if that is what expected.

Maybe you can try running something like below

```
WITH  (SELECT * FROM dbo.userdiagnosis  
    INNER JOIN dbo.diagnosis ON dbo.userdiagnosis.diagnosisid = dbo.diagnosis.id ) AS diagnosisDetails,
SELECT  dbo.usermedication.id, \
    dbo.medicine.id AS medicationid,  \
    dbo.medicine.medname, \
    dbo.usermedication.isactive, \
    dbo.usermedication.reminder, \
    dbo.usermedication.communityfeedback, \
    dbo.usermedication.frequency, \
    dbo.usermedication.directions, \
    dbo.medicine.dosage, \
    dbo.usermedication.datetimetotake,  \
    DiagnosisDetails.id as "userdiagnosisid", \
    DiagnosisDetails.diagnosistext \
    FROM dbo.usermedication 
    INNER JOIN dbo.medicine ON dbo.usermedication.medicationid = 
dbo.medicine.id  
    LEFT JOIN diagnosisDetails ON dbo.usermedication.userdiagnosisid = diagnosisDetails.id  
    WHERE dbo.usermedication.userid = @userid AND dbo.usermedication.isactive = 1;
```

Comment: Would i not need a left or right join going from the usermedication table to the userdiagnosis table and then a left join going from the userdiagnosis table to the diagnosis table ?

Comment: Use Inner Join when you need to fetch the details. for ex: diagnosis details. Therefore, use INNER JOIN between userDiagnosis and Diagnosis tables. But between userMedication and userDiagnosis, try using LEFT JOIN. I assume that there will always be a record inserted into userMedication table.

Comment: Tried that, still no joy. Yes their is a record inserted into the usermedication table everytime. The userdiagnosisid field on the usermedication is only populated when a diagnosis is entered otherwise it is currently blank.

Comment: Have updated the answer with sample query.. Maybe it works for you to fetch the records as expected.

Comment: See the thing is i dont need any of information from the userdiagnosis table or diagnosis table unless the user enters a diagnosis. If i edit my data and add a userdiagnosisid in the usermedication table the form will show that field otherwise it wont appear